# Functionality of adding to lists in Haskell / overwriting an existing List

Tags: list, haskell, overwrite, addition

```
type Dictionary = [(String, String)]

dict :: Dictionary
dict = ("Deutsch", "English"):[]

insert :: Dictionary -> (String,String) -> Dictionary
insert dict entry = dict ++ [entry]
```

One thing that I didn't find about the way lists work: Is it somehow possible to overwrite the existing dict with the entry added in insert? Or is it necessary to, in the next step, always write out the list that was put out by insert?

```
insert [("German", "English"), ("Hallo", "hello")] ("Versuch", "try")
```

So far, this is the only way I have been able to add something to the new list without losing the previous entry. However, next on the list of things to implement is a search command, so I wonder if I'd also have to write this out in the search function.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "write this out"? By the way, the rigt hand side of your insert function would be better simply `entry:dict`

Comment: If you're creating an association list, if you insert at the front of the list then you don't need to remove the previous value since any search will find the item added most recently.

Comment: I already tried using the cons operator, but it seems like my list, as it stands, is no association list? Because I encounter the same problem when I change the operator from ++ to :, all I ever got was one additional entry without renaming everything like in RasmusWriedtLarsen's example.

@Ingo What I meant was NOT giving the new lists names with let dict2 an so on, but rather write the entire list with its entries like in the insert command I wrote in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of functional programming is in general that your data is immutable. This means once you have created a list, you can NEVER change that list. But you can copy that list, make modifications to it, and keep that as well.

So when you have a list like so

```
test = [1,2,3]
```

We can modify this by adding `4` to the start:

```
test2 = 4 : test
```

`:` called the cons operator, puts an element in front of a list. Do note that `x:xs` (the same as doing `[x]++xs`) has a better performance than doing `xs++[x]`

So now we have two bindings, one of `test` to `[1,2,3]` and one of `test2` to `[4,1,2,3]`

Hope this clarifies things

---

To give a full example:

```
type Dictionary = [(String, String)]

insert :: Dictionary -> (String,String) -> Dictionary
insert dict entry = dict ++ [entry]

dict0 = [ ("Deutsch", "English") ]
dict1 = insert dict0 ("Hallo", "hello")
dict2 = insert dict1 ("Versuch", "try")
```

---

If you're new to functional programming, I would recommend reading [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) , which is a fantastic (and free) book on how to use Haskell -- and functional programming in general.

Comment: If I try to do this in the command line, I would have to add let first, right? like `let dict1 = insert dict0 ("Hallo", "Hello")`?

Comment: dict ++ [entry] -- adding one element to the end of list is very bad in terms of performance. Why don't just use the colon operator?

Comment: I thought it would be clever to have the headline ("Deutsch", "English") at the head of the list, and if I add to the beginning of the list, the head would constantly change, wouldn't it? @user2894391

Comment: @dschib Changing of head is the cheapest list operation so it is preferable then possible.

Comment: Wouldn't I have to do this permanently once I prepend a new element with `:`? Or is there a way to let the head stick?

Comment: If doing something like this, you would probably not add the name of the languages to the lists, as it's implicit. It kinda breaks the information contained in the the list, where you have a tuple of a word in (Deutsch, English) ... but ("Deutsch", "English") is certainly not the same thing in two different languages.

Comment: So I'll just leave it out and add the words, well, then prepending should indeed be no problem. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: The only problem being that let is exclusive to GHCi, while I'm stuck with hugs at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

It's not too tough to do this

```
import Data.List (lookup)

insert :: Eq a => (a,b) -> [(a,b)] -> [(a,b)]
insert (a,b)  []           = [(a,b)]
insert (a,b) ((c,d):rest) = if a == c
    then (a,b) : rest
    else (c,d) : insert (a,b) rest

---

dict :: [(String, String)]
dict = [("Deutsch", "English")]
```

If you can't use `Data.List` then you can define `lookup` by

```
lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a,b)] -> Maybe b
lookup _  []          = Nothing
lookup k ((a,b):rest) = if k == a then Just b else lookup k rest
```

Now if you load up GHCI:

```
>> let dict' = insert ("Ein","One") dict
>> dict'
[("Deutsch","English"),("Ein","One")]
>> lookup "Ein" dict'
Just "One"
>> insert ("Deutsch", "Francais") dict'
[("Deutsch","Francais"),("Ein","One")]
```

Comment: The thing about this task is to not do it with Data.List since we aren't that far right now and still have to grasp the basics of functional programming.

Comment: @dschib I edited to remove the dependency on `Data.List`

Comment: Thanks a lot, the lookup function will help me out greatly!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace an existing pair with the same key then you could write insert as:

```
insert :: Dictionary -> (String, String) -> Dictionary
insert [] p = [p]
insert ((dk, dv):ps) p@(k, v) | dk == k = p:ps
insert (p:ps) ip = p : (insert ps ip)
```

However if you are writing an association list, then you can simplify it by inserting new items at the front of the list:

```
insert :: Dictionary -> (String, String) -> Dictionary
insert = flip (:)
```

if you then search from the front of the list, it will find any values added more recently first.

Answer (score 0):

In Haskell, most values are *immutable*, meaning that you can not change their value.  This seems like a huge constraint at first, but in reality it makes it easier to reason about your program, especially when using multiple threads.

What you can do instead is continually call `insert` on the dictionary returned when you call `insert`, for example:

```
mainLoop :: Dictionary -> IO ()
mainLoop dict = do
    putStrLn "Enter the German word:"
    german <- getLine
    putStrLn "Enter the English word:
    english <- getLine
    let newDict = insert dict (german, english)
    putStrLn "Continue? (y/n)"
    yesno <- getChar
    if yesno == 'y'
        then mainLoop newDict
        else print newDict

main = do
```

Comment: I would love to work with IO, however that is far from where we are in our lecture right now. All we should do is use the insert command in the command line, without prompts or anything of the sort.
The main problem I had with understanding this is if there is anyway to have dict NOT be immutable, but I guess that is like trying to throw pearls before the swine.

Comment: Not without IO.  You could use the State monad, but if IO is beyond your current lectures, that is too.  Right now you'll just have to keep rebinding it as @RasmusWriedtLarsen suggests.

Answer (score 0):

One simply can't 'overwrite' anything in a pure language (outside of ST monad). If I understood your question correctly, you are looking for something like this:

```
insert :: Dictionary -> (String,String) -> Dictionary
insert [] b = [b]  -- If this point is reached where wasn't matching key in dictionary, so we just insert a new pair
insert (h@(k, v) : t) b@(k', v')
    | k == k'   = (k, v') : t      -- We found a matching pair, so we 'update' its value
    | otherwise = h : insert t b
```

Comment: The check for duplicates is not necessary in my task, the main problem I had with my understanding is seein how every dict I define is immutable as it is, so if I want to have a new name for a dict that has more than one entry I would have to use `let dict3 = insert dict2 ("This", "that")`.

Comment: @dschib You may use state monad to simulate variables.

Comment: Again, something I can look up in the future, the last thing we had in our lecture were arrays, and monads are a long way down the road...