# Why this dictionary function is not working

Tags: dictionary, haskell, compiler-errors, type-mismatch, do-notation

I am trying to create and use a dictionary with code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20567255/functionality-of-adding-to-lists-in-haskell-overwriting-an-existing-list):

```
import Data.List (lookup)

insert :: Eq a => (a,b) -> [(a,b)] -> [(a,b)]
insert (a,b)  []           = [(a,b)]
insert (a,b) ((c,d):rest) = if a == c
    then (a,b) : rest
    else (c,d) : insert (a,b) rest

dict :: [(String, String)]
dict = [("", "")]

main = do 
    insert ("onekey", "onevalue") dict
    print dict
    print $ lookup "onekey" dict
```

But I am getting following error:

```
$ runghc rndict.hs

rndict.hs:22:1: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘IO t0’ with actual type ‘[()]’
    • In the expression: main
      When checking the type of the IO action ‘main’

rndict.hs:24:9: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘[]’
      Expected type: [()]
        Actual type: IO ()
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: print dict
      In the expression:
        do { insert ("onekey", "onevalue") dict;
             print dict;
             print $ lookup "onekey" dict }
      In an equation for ‘main’:
          main
            = do { insert ("onekey", "onevalue") dict;
                   print dict;
                   print $ lookup "onekey" dict }

rndict.hs:25:9: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘[]’
      Expected type: [()]
        Actual type: IO ()
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: print $ lookup "onekey" dict
      In the expression:
        do { insert ("onekey", "onevalue") dict;
             print dict;
             print $ lookup "onekey" dict }
      In an equation for ‘main’:
          main
            = do { insert ("onekey", "onevalue") dict;
                   print dict;
                   print $ lookup "onekey" dict }
```

What is the problem and what is the correct way to use dictionaries in Haskell?

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50815136/849891) for a general description of [tag:do-notation].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `let` to bind the new dictionary to a name:

```
import Data.List (lookup)

insert :: Eq a => (a,b) -> [(a,b)] -> [(a,b)]
insert (a,b)  []           = [(a,b)]
insert (a,b) ((c,d):rest) = if a == c
    then (a,b) : rest
    else (c,d) : insert (a,b) rest

dict :: [(String, String)]
dict = [("", "")]

main = do
    let d = insert ("onekey", "onevalue") dict
    print d
    print $ lookup "onekey" d
```

You ask about inserting multiple elements. For this you could use a fold to write a function called `insertMany`. You should probably be using `foldl'` but I'll leave that as an exercise to find out why.

```
import Data.List (lookup)

insert :: Eq a => (a,b) -> [(a,b)] -> [(a,b)]
insert (a,b)  []           = [(a,b)]
insert (a,b) ((c,d):rest) = if a == c
    then (a,b) : rest
    else (c,d) : insert (a,b) rest

insertMany :: Eq a => [(a,b)] -> [(a,b)] -> [(a,b)]
insertMany elements dict =
  foldl (flip insert) dict elements

dict :: [(String, String)]
dict = [("", "")]

main = do
    let d = insert ("onekey", "onevalue") dict
    print d
    print $ lookup "onekey" d
    print $ insertMany [("onekey", "newvalue"), ("anotherkey", "anothervalue")]
      dict
```

Comment: Can I not change original dictionary using `let dict =...`

Comment: You would not change it, but introduce a name that shadows the original name.

Comment: I have to repeat this insert process many times. I see that it is not working on second time itself.

Comment: Notice that `insert` does not mutate, but returns a new dictionary every time. If you need to insert many elements, you can make a function `insertMany` that uses a fold or recursion.

Comment: Ok. I need that as the answer please.

Comment: `let`'s bindings are recursive so it wouldn't work with the same name, `let dict = ....dict....`. Instead, *inside a `do` block*, you *can* write `dict <- return (....dict....)`, even if it's a bit hackish. That *will* create a new name shadowing the previous one.

Comment: Dictionaries / association lists are very useful and there in most languages. What is the correct way to create, add multiple items and to lookup an item to a dictionary in Haskell. That is what I am trying to understand.

Comment: see [how to increment a variable in functional programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922134/how-to-increment-a-variable-in-functional-programming).

Comment: `d <- (return insert ("2key", "2value") d)` does not work. Gives error: `Couldn't match type ‘[(a0, b0)] -> [(a0, b0)]’                     with ‘IO [([Char], b1)]’`

Comment: @rnso I added an example of `insertMany`.

Comment: perhaps `insertMany [("onekey", "newvalue"), ("anotherkey", "anothervalue")]`?

Comment: @rnso that should've been `d <- return (insert ("2key", "2value") d)`. And yes, you can repeat that as many time as you'd like. Although, it will definitely be bad style; using a fold-based function is much more idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer. I would be great if you could also mention if and how I can do `let d = insert (k, v) dict` multiple times to the same `d` with varying values of `k` and `v`.